# Comportamiento de un Activity como Dialog

Tags: android, diálogo

Deseo conseguir lo siguiente, como puede ver un `Dialog` en la parte superior tiene un icono circular de **cerrar(x)**. Tengo el `Dialog` pero necesito el icono mencionado, ¿ alguna idea para conseguir esto o algo similar ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He convertido un **Layout** normal en `Dialog`, de esta forma. En el *manifests* he aplicado el siguiente **Style**

**Style**

```
 <style name="formularios" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@color/formulario</item>
        <item name="android:radius">@dimen/from</item>
    </style>
```

y luego en el **manifests** aplico el estilo

```
android:theme="@style/formularios"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es crear un **CustomDialog** el cual lo vas a conformar a partir de un `Layout` común y corriente con *background* transparente, puedes usar una imagen para colocar ahí tus opciones como por ejemplo el botón de cerrar. Generalmente yo usaba *frameLayout*.

Ya en tu actividad llenas tu diálogo con el `layout` que hayas creado:

**Te dejo un ejemplo completo para que  le entiendas mucho mejor**

```
 private void alert_win() {

        //** Aquí empieza la parte que nos interesa**

        dialog = new Dialog(GameScreen.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));//Aquí le das ele efecto de transparencia
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.winner_dialog);//Aquí cargas el layout
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); //Evita cerrar el diálogo cuando tocas fuera de el.

 //** Aquí termina la parte que nos interesa**


        Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bellosmcp.ttf");

        TextView moTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.moTextView);
        moTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        moTextView.setText(String.valueOf(_turn_count));
        TextView matchTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.matchTextView);
        matchTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        movesTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        matchTextView.setText(String.valueOf(_score));
        TextView pairstextView =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairstextView);
        pairstextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        pairstextView.setText(Integer.toString(c));
        ImageView closeDialog = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        TextView highScoreTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.high_Score);
        highScoreTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        highScoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(user.high_score));


.......
         //** Aquí colocas un button o imagebutton que cierre el diálogo**  
        closeDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    go_home();
                    send_score();
                }
                //display_unlocked_card_alert();


                display_unlocked_card_alert();


            }
        });


        ImageButton resetGame =(ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.resetGame);
        resetGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                    reset_game();

                display_unlocked_card_alert();




            }
        });

        dialog.show();

        Log.d(  TAG,"unlocked_check value 2 = " + unlocked_check);
    }
```

**Layout de contenido del Diálogo**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/winner"><![CDATA[
  android:padding="10dip">

    ]]>

    <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/about_logo"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:src="@drawable/fondo_score"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/high_score"
        android:id="@+id/highScore"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gameResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/this_match"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/close"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="230dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/try_again_efects_image"
        android:id="@+id/resetGame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pairstextView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/gameResults"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <TextView style="@style/match_results"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="This match"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="-1"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/matchTextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/moTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp" />

    <TextView style="@style/match_results"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Moves"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="-1"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/moTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/matchTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView style="@style/match_results"
        android:id="@+id/pairstextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pairs"
        android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
        android:shadowDx="-1"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gameResults"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp" />

    <TextView style="@style/high_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/high_Score"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_close_dialog"
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/copa"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Eso queda de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver puedes crear un dialogo a partir un layout o lo que tu quieras, yo uso este tipo de diálogos cuando requiero un con muchas opciones o bien uno que  no mantenga el aspecto común.

Comment: Esta función va dentro del mismo layout ?

Comment: ¿Cómo? Creas un layout, ejemplo tienes dos: dialogo.xml y mainactivity.xml, dentro de tu actividad del layout donde quieres que se muestre el dialogo, por ejemplo en MainActivity colocas esa función.

Comment: voy a llamar un dialogo cuando abra el main y este estará "encima" del layout?

Comment: En sí, se comporta como un diálogo común y corriente, ya que estará encima del layout donde se llame, la única diferencia es que es custom, es decir, está compuesto por un layout. Puedes llamarlo de donde quieras, desde un botón, al inicio, etc. ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: el problema era que yo tenia ya construido todo en un solo layout he intente añadir este icono sin llamar otro dialogo, pero funciona como tu lo has descrito

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes, es todo un tema de maquetación te propongo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El contenedor celeste seria el padre o la vista principal del DialogFragment puede ser un RelativeLayout.
- El contenedor rojo seria el cerrar botón alineado a la derecha con margenes como lo necesites y le colocas el id "@+id/btn_cerrar".
- El contenedor verde debajo del boton de "cerrar" maquetarias un segundo hijo LinearLayout podria ser en este caso para el panel de opciones usa el atributo layout_below="@id/btn_cerrar" por ejemplo.

ahora al contenedor padre le vas a colocar un background transparente eso es para que parezca que el botón del "cerrar" esta en el aire o flotando.

y al contendedor debajo del "cerrar" o el LinearLayout le colocar un drawable hecho por ti que tenga un fondo blanco borde redondeados o lo que necesites y listo ya con eso queda.

ya solo queda de tu parte hacer la programación de lo que hace cada botón.

así es como yo lo haría y ya me a tocado hacer este tipo de cosas.

Comment: He intentado esto pero no consigo que el icono, quede en la parte superior...